# Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) while installing gnome control center data

Tags: gnome, dpkg

I was trying to install gnome control center data and got this error 
Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y gnome-control-center-data
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  geoclue-2.0 gnome-control-center-faces gnome-startup-applications humanity-icon-theme libasn1-8-heimdal libgssapi3-heimdal
  libhcrypto4-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal libheimntlm0-heimdal libhx509-5-heimdal libkrb5-26-heimdal libnetplan0 libroken18-heimdal
  libwind0-heimdal networkd-dispatcher ubuntu-mono
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  gnome-control-center-data
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 136 not upgraded.
72 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/3,627 kB of archives.
After this operation, 15.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 308721 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gnome-control-center-data_1%3a3.36.2-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-control-center-data (1:3.36.2-1) over (1:3.36.1-1ubuntu5) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-control-center-data_1%3a3.36.2-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/pixmaps/faces/bicycle.jpg', which is also in package gnome-control-center-faces 1:3.36.2-0ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-control-center-data_1%3a3.36.2-1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: It's right there in your output: "*trying to overwrite '/usr/share/pixmaps/faces/bicycle.jpg', which is also in package gnome-control-center-faces 1:3.36.2-0ubuntu1*"

Comment: gnome-control-center-data_1:3.36.2-1_all.deb is not an Ubuntu version number, so that package is not coming from the Ubuntu repositories. Looks like you are trying to mix Gnome packages from two different sources, which seems unwise.

Comment: Hmmm: "*136 not upgraded. 72 not fully installed or removed*" Your system has real troubles.